# Counting the number of correlated sales relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Looking for a little assistance on a Cypher query. Given a set of customers `peer` who own book `p`, I am able to retrieve a set of customers `target` who own at least one book also owned by `peer` but who don't own `p`. This is accomplished using the following query:

```
match 
(p:Book {isbn:"123456"})<-[:owns]-(peer:Customer)
  -[:owns]->(other:Book)<-[o:owns]-(target:Customer)
WHERE NOT( (target)-[:owns]->(p))
return target.name
limit 10;
```

My next step is to determine *how many* `other` books each member of the `target` set own, and order those members accordingly. I've attempted several variations based on the Neo4j documentation and SO answers, but am having no luck. For instance I tried using `with`:

```
match 
  (p:Book {isbn:"123456"})<-[:owns]-(peer:Customer)
  -[:owns]->(other:Book)<-[o:owns]-(target:Customer)
WHERE NOT( (target)-[:owns]->(p))
WITH target, count(o) as co
WHERE co > 1
return target.name
limit 10;
```

I also tried what seems to my novice eye was the most reasonable query:

```
match 
  (p:Book {isbn:"123456"})<-[:owns]-(peer:Customer)
  -[:owns]->(other:Book)<-[o:owns]-(target:Customer)
WHERE NOT( (target)-[:owns]->(p))
return target.name, count(o)
limit 10;
```

In both of these cases, the query just runs without end (upwards of 10 minutes before I stop execution). Any insight into what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**
As it turns out this latter query does execute but takes 15 minutes to complete and is reporting incorrect numbers, as evidenced here:

```
+-------------------------------+
| target.name        | count(o) |
+-------------------------------+
| "John Smith"       | 12840    |
| "Mary Moore"       | 11501    |
+-------------------------------+
```

I'm looking for the number of books each customer specifically owns, not sure where these `12840` and `11501` numbers are coming from really. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have an index on :Book(isbn)? Btw first query has "pisbn"--is it supposed to be "isbn"?

Comment: Fixed that typo, this was me mistyping the query, ugh. I've just created a gist: http://console.neo4j.org/r/sk39pk. What is baffling (to me) is that the query works exactly as advertised (with an admittedly very small data set). Perhaps the query just needs to run for quite a bit to complete? Going to check the index now.

Comment: I do indeed have the index set: 
    $ schema
    Indexes
      ON :Book(isbn) ONLINE

Is it possible to view query status, akin to MySQL's `show processlist`? This seems to me one of the rather mysterious aspects of Neo4j it is difficult to monitor what exactly is going on when a query is executing.

Comment: Hey @WesFreeman ok I'm getting somewhere, see the edit above, as it turns out the query does execute bu the number of customer-owned books it's returning is obviously inaccurate. Getting close! Any ideas?

Comment: It's finding an o for each matching book that any peer owns. Distinct will fix, but I think you can rewrite, I'll post an answer now that I think I understand more of what you're doing.

Comment: That was it! I see what is going now per the use of `WITH` in conjunction with `DISTINCT`. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one:

```
MATCH (p:Book {isbn:"123456"})<-[:owns]-(peer:Customer)
WITH distinct peer, p
MATCH (peer)-[:owns]->(other:Book)
WITH distinct other, p
MATCH (other)<-[o:owns]-(target:Customer)
WHERE NOT((target)-[:owns]->(p))
RETURN target.name, count(o)
LIMIT 10;
```